# Is it possible to use HTML5 canvas API to batch generate images non-interactively via script?

Tags: python, browser, html5-canvas, batch-processing

Currently, when I need to create some images for scientific visualization (generally, from CSV files or other data-container), I use Python as scripting language, and Cairo as drawing API. It allows me to run a script, and have a directory full of .png files.

Although Cairo is a very nice drawing API, I see Canvas, besides being more mainstream, has some operations (like compositing and swadowing), which would make possible to create more sophisticated graphics, among other potential advantages.

The main problem I see is being browser-based, so I think the script would have to call a scriptable browser, which has the actual canvas rendering engine. I don't even know if the concept of "scriptable browser" (via command line) exists at all.

Other not-so-big problem would be the need for a running HTTP server, but I think Python provides `SimpleHTTPServer` which should work fine.

Any idea?

Thanks for reading, hope it helps more people in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Great ambitious idea!

It is possible to script the opening of a browser and create images; saving them might be a little difficult.

You could write an HTML file including your scripts, then use Python's [webbrowser](http://docs.python.org/library/webbrowser.html) module to open that file in a browser window-- you can set up a trivial webserver or use a `file://` URI to do it.

Setting up a trivial webserver might be worth it as support for XMLHttpRequests to `file://` URIs is not guaranteed, even on the "same domain".

You could write your Javascript to take an arbitrary (local) URI, use XHR to fetch its contents, and process it.  An easy way to pass that local URI would be to parse it out of the fragment string-- a janky approach if ever there were one, but it sees use in Twitter so it can't be too bad, right?

Then render each one of your images to canvas and check out Eli Grey's [FileSaver](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js) and... you might have to click a button a bazillion times to save all your images.

Best of luck-- I'm curious to hear how it goes.

Comment: Great suggestions. I was wondering if I could add an "autosave" function in javascript, inside the very html file. When I have some news, I'll get back to post. If no other answer appears, I'll come back to accept this! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

How about [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/)? It has a `render` method that will output images; see the [Interface docs](http://code.google.com/p/phantomjs/wiki/Interface).

Comment: This sounds nice. I am not so involved with it right now, but for sure I'll use this information as soon as I get back to it. Thanks!